# Build a JSON document from a sqlite table

Tags: json, sqlite

I've been looking at the JSON1 extension for SQLite databases as a potential tool to use to compose a JSON document from a table-valued result.

I have a result set coming out of my SQLite database that resembles something like this:

```
CLASS|INSTANCE|PROPERTY|FROM|TO
ABC|12345|COLOR|RED|
ABC|12345|COLOR|GREEN|
ABC|12345|WEIGHT|1|10
ABC|56789|COLOR|BLUE|
ABC|56789|HEIGHT|4.5|6.2
DEF|2345|NAME|YOMOMMA|
```

I've been trying to make a JSON document based off of this data to look like:

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "12345": {
            "COLOR": [
                { "from": "RED", "to": "" },
                { "from": "GREEN", "to": ""}
            ],
            "WEIGHT": [
                { "from": "1", "to": "10" }
            ]
        },
        "56789": {
            "COLOR": [
                { "from": "BLUE", "to": "" }
            ],
            "HEIGHT": [
                { "from": "4.5", "to": "6.2" }
            ]
        }
    },
    "DEF": {
        "2345": {
            "NAME": [
                { "from": "YOMOMMA", "to": "" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to get the JSON1 functions to help me out with this, but it seems they don't really support a multilayered JSON format (or at least, not that I've been able to see).  If I wrap my result set in a group by query, I can get the properties to nicely turn into a JSON array, but when I try to wrap that into the next level, all the JSON gets escaped (would have been nice if there was a json_raw() function, but I'd imagine implementing it would be challenging).

Can this be done (relatively) easily using SQLite/ JSON1? Is there a different/ better way to create my document than using JSON1, or am I just going to have to write code for this?

Comment: This looks to me like a task that's better done outside of SQL...

Comment: I don't disagree; that being said, I'm merely trying to format the data for another process to consume, and I'd like to avoid adding another step in the workflow if I don't have to.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) say: *"The `json_object()` SQL function accepts zero or more pairs of arguments and returns a well-formed JSON object that is composed from those arguments."*, where any of those arguments may be a JSON string itself. In other words, it can parse one level of JSON - can you use that to effectively un-nest the JSON from your subqueries? Just an untested thought.

Comment: @Tomalak the problem is, if you nest it, it starts escaping JSON characters like curly braces and double quotes... treats inner JSON as a character string...